# Scikit-learn Naive Bayes inexplicable results with sparse string classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Im trying to use the scikit learn module for text classification. its a dataset that has lots of unique words. the nature of which will be apparent from the following example,

```
train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(data)
train_counts.shape

print len(range(len(data)-1)) 

clf = MultinomialNB(alpha=1).fit(train_counts, range(len(data)) )

docs_new = ['Modern Warfare 2', 'Modern Warfare 3', 'Modern Warfare 1', 'Modern Warfare 4', 'Modern Warfare', 'Mahjong Kakutou Club', 'Mass Effect 2']

new_counts = count_vect.transform(docs_new)
predicted = clf.predict(new_counts)

for doc, category in zip(docs_new, predicted):
    print '%r => %s' % (doc, target_names[category])
```

and the output looks like this.

```
763
'Modern Warfare 2' => Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 3
'Modern Warfare 3' => Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 3
'Modern Warfare 1' => Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 3
'Modern Warfare 4' => Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 3
'Modern Warfare' => Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 3
'Mahjong Kakutou Club' => Mahjong Kakutou Club
'Mass Effect 2' => Mass Effect 2
```

This is a multinomial example, but i get identical results with a bernoulli example. i have tried with alpha values from 0 to 1000000. can anyone explain to me why this is the case?

EDIT: I should have made it clear, the following classes exist Call of Duty: Modern Warfare, Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 2... most other games, the list of all play-station games was taken from wikipedia.

also, the full versions, eg Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 2 as a test string produces the same result

i was originally using the NLTK classifier but for some reason it didn't place much value words like "Kakutou" which were not present in any other examples. (obviously the Scikit one does) It didnt have the problem with the numbers like the scikit classifier does.

Any guidance or information here would be immensely valuable.

Thanks

Edit: the data set is from here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PlayStation_3_games its the first column, each example is has a lable and content that are the same

Comment: what is your train data? is it documents with 2-3 words long?

Comment: its a list of video games, they range from 1 to about 10 words long.

Comment: I think you should go over the tutorial [this](http://scikit-learn.github.com/scikit-learn-tutorial/working_with_text_data.html) tutorial

Comment: Could you be more specific as to why? I already have...

Comment: According to the tutorial you should have around 100000 words in your train data over thousands of documents in order to get meaningful results. Maybe I don't understand what you are trying to do here but it seems that you have only one document per class in your train data, which is the name of the class itself?

Comment: Yes that is correct, i am trying to evaluate naive bayes classification for specific multi class problem. Actually the tutorial says that typically training sets would have 100000 words. it doesn't actually say that you should have that many.

Comment: `clf = MultinomialNB(alpha=1).fit(train_counts, range(len(data)) )` means that you have one class per sample. I don't see how you would expect anything to be able to generalize by seeing only one example per class and having as many distinct classes as examples.

Comment: I understand the issue of the lack of data, but i understood that the math behind naive bayes classification should work. every class has a set of words where their combination is unique to that class. given the number of words that wont be found to be in any given example, when words are found they should have a huge effect. This is shown by the fact that except for the single digit numbers it seems to be working quite well at classifying examples that were in the sample data. 'Agent' => Agent
'2010 FIFA World Cup South Africa' => 2010 FIFA World Cup South Africa

Comment: I don't understand where `target_names` come from in your example and how they could possibly relate to the training targets of your snippet that are `range(len(data))` hence different for each training sample hence nothing can be generalized and the model will only be able to learn stuff by heart which is useless.

Comment: if you take a look at the example in th elink Zenpoy gives in the third comment, it says that you shouldn't use the actual target names but use list indices. range(len(data)) just generates a list of incremented numbers that i can use to map back to the individual target names. but yes in this case each class only has a single sample. i know its not what NB classifiers are designed for, but I'm just exploring the application to my specific field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code does not show how count_vect is constructed, but if it just a default initialized `CountVectorizer`, then it ignores character tokens (ie the series numbers) making all "Modern Warfare..." titles tokenize the same as "Modern Warfare":

```
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer as CV
>>> count_vect=CV()
>>> docs_new = ['Modern Warfare 2', 'Modern Warfare 3', 'Modern Warfare 1', 'Modern Warfare 4', 'Modern Warfare A', 'Modern Warfare 44', 'Modern Warfare AA', 'Modern Warfare', 'Mahjong Kakutou Club', 'Mass Effect 2']
>>> new_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(docs_new)
>>> count_vect.inverse_transform(new_counts)
[array([u'modern', u'warfare'], 
      dtype='<U7'), array([u'modern', u'warfare'], 
      dtype='<U7'), array([u'modern', u'warfare'], 
      dtype='<U7'), array([u'modern', u'warfare'], 
      dtype='<U7'), array([u'modern', u'warfare'], 
      dtype='<U7'), array([u'44', u'modern', u'warfare'], 
      dtype='<U7'), array([u'aa', u'modern', u'warfare'], 
      dtype='<U7'), array([u'modern', u'warfare'], 
      dtype='<U7'), array([u'club', u'kakutou', u'mahjong'], 
      dtype='<U7'), array([u'effect', u'mass'], 
      dtype='<U7')]
```

This is because scikit vectorizers have the default setting `token_pattern=r'(?u)\b\w\w+\b'`
The model is just breaking the ties arbitrarily, since neither training nor prediction see any difference between those titles. You can get around this by using `token_pattern=r'(?u)\b\w+\b'`

```
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer as CV
>>> count_vect=CV(token_pattern=r'(?u)\b\w+\b')
>>> docs_new = ['Modern Warfare 2', 'Modern Warfare 3', 'Modern Warfare 1', 'Modern Warfare 4', 'Modern Warfare A', 'Modern Warfare 44', 'Modern Warfare AA', 'Modern Warfare', 'Mahjong Kakutou Club', 'Mass Effect 2']
>>> new_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(docs_new)
>>> count_vect.inverse_transform(new_counts)
[array([u'2', u'modern', u'warfare'], 
      dtype='<U7'), array([u'3', u'modern', u'warfare'], 
      dtype='<U7'), array([u'1', u'modern', u'warfare'], 
      dtype='<U7'), array([u'4', u'modern', u'warfare'], 
      dtype='<U7'), array([u'a', u'modern', u'warfare'], 
      dtype='<U7'), array([u'44', u'modern', u'warfare'], 
      dtype='<U7'), array([u'aa', u'modern', u'warfare'], 
      dtype='<U7'), array([u'modern', u'warfare'], 
      dtype='<U7'), array([u'club', u'kakutou', u'mahjong'], 
      dtype='<U7'), array([u'2', u'effect', u'mass'], 
      dtype='<U7')]
```

Comment: Where were you a year and half ago! You are spot on, I did work that out in the end to great success, unfortunately, I forgot to add the solution myself. Thanks.